# Black Screen displayed on cancelling phone call +ios5

Tags: ios5

I have a web view in my app where the phone numbers are highlighted. 
When user taps on the phone link, he gets an alert with "Cancel" and "call" button. 
when user taps "call"(attends call), my app goes in background and calling screen is displayed. 
But on calling screen, if user "cancel" the call, black screen is displayed and my app is not resumed back. I have observed this behavior on iOS 5 devices.
Please help.

We can simulate this by loading a html page containing a phone number in web view.L The html will look like this:

> `<html><head></head><body><br>12-534-1672</body></html>`